# Learning Events

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am currently trying to teach myself how to use events but I can never seem to make everything work properly.

The class with the event coding looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace EventsPractice
{
    public delegate void myEventHandler(string newValue);

    public class EventExample
    {
        private string _value;
        public event myEventHandler valueChanged;

        public string val
        {
            set
            {
                _value = value;
                valueChanged(_value);
            }
        }

        static void myEvt_valueChanged(string newValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The value changed to {0}", newValue);
        }
    }
}
```

My Program class looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using EventsPractice;

namespace EventsPractice
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EventExample myEvt = new EventExample();

            myEvt.valueChanged += myEventHandler(myEvt_valueChanged);

            string str;
            do
            {
                str = Console.ReadLine();
                if (!str.Equals("exit"))
                    myEvt.val = str;
            } while (!str.Equals("exit"));

        }
    }
}
```

The errors I am receiving are:

"Error 1   'EventsPractice.myEventHandler' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EventsPractice\EventsPractice\Program.cs   15  35  EventsPractice"

Error   2   The name 'myEvt_valueChanged' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EventsPractice\EventsPractice\Program.cs   15  50  EventsPractice

I am unsure what I am missing or where I went wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for subscribing to an event requires that you provide an instance of a delegate object on the right-hand-side of the `+=` operator. The expression `myEventHandler(myEvt_valueChanged);` isn't meaningful at all, never mind does it provide the necessary delegate instance.

The other issue is that the identifier `myEvt_valueChanged` isn't valid on its own, where you are trying to use it. The method by that name is declared in a completely different class, and so has to be qualified by the class name if you want to use it outside of that class. That way the compiler can tell where to find the method.

The simplest way to change your code would be to add the `new` operator, like so:

```
myEvt.valueChanged += new myEventHandler(EventExample.myEvt_valueChanged);
```

This will explicitly create an instance of the `myEventHandler` delegate type, using the method `myEvt_valueChanged` from the `EventExample` class. However, C# offers a more concise syntax in which it will infer the delegate type and `new` operator on your behalf, based on the left-hand-side of the expression:

```
myEvt.valueChanged += EventExample.myEvt_valueChanged;
```

Note that when you write it this way, it is still doing exactly the same thing as if you'd written the whole thing explicitly. It's just that the compiler is filling in the obvious parts for you.

Finally, I will point out that events are most often used by subscribing a method *not* from the same class where the event is declared. Your example above would be more typical if the `myEvt_valueChanged` method were in the `Program` class, and if it were there instead, you wouldn't need to specify the class name when subscribing it to the event:

```
myEvt.valueChanged += myEvt_valueChanged;
```

Answer (score 0):

At the right hand of the `+=` you have to put a method (or a lambda) that have the same signature as the `delegate`, something like:

```
 myEvt.valueChanged += (val) => { Console.WriteLine("Value is now {0}", val); }
```

or

```
private void SomeMethod(string val) {
    Console.WriteLine("Value is now {0}", val);
}

myEvt.valueChanged += SomeMethod;
```